# Why do I get: -9223372036854775808

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int64_t splitAdd(int64_t value) {
    ostringstream intStream;
    intStream << value;
    string intString(intStream.str());
    return accumulate(intString.begin(), intString.end(), 0) - (intString.size() * int64_t('0'));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int64_t maxPower = 50;
    int64_t results[maxPower];
    for (int64_t tuple = 0; tuple <= maxPower; tuple++) {
        for(int64_t power = 0; power <= maxPower; power++) {
            int64_t value = pow(tuple, power);
            while (value > 9) {
                value = splitAdd(value);
            }
            results[power] = value;
        }
        cout << tuple << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxPower; i++) {
            cout << results[i] << ',';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

After a while, I get the value: -9223372036854775808 repeatedly. I'm running this in Code Runner 2 also, not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Where did you get this code?

Comment: `int64_t maxPower = 50;   int64_t results[maxPower];`  This is not valid ANSI C++.

Comment: I'm trying to find repeating patterns in infinite series of numbers

Comment: @August Why not print out intermediate values, or better yet, use the debugger, to see where / when the numbers go awry?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I changed it to results[50] and I still get -9223372036854775808...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: here's a screen Shot: http://snap.auguststurm.com/1kZ08/irGByTv5

Comment: Why the down vote?! If I knew how to ask the question or the reason I'm getting this I wouldn't have asked..

Comment: Don't know who downvoted.  Usually a "close" vote would be cast for a question on "why doesn't this work", not a downvote.  .

Comment: -9223372036854775808 is -Int64, or a minimal value int64_t can hold an i.e. 0x8000000000000000.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one glaring error is this:

```
int64_t maxPower = 50;
int64_t results[maxPower];  // <-- Not really legal, but let's pretend
//...
for (int64_t power = 0; 
             power <= maxPower; // <-- Look at the loop constraints
             power++) 
{  
    //....
}
results[power] = value;  // <-- Buffer overrun
```

Since `maxPower` is 50, you are accessing an element that's out of bounds.  This is *undefined behavior*

Also, to make the code legal C++, either declare an array of 50:

```
int64_t results[50];
```

or declare a `std::vector<int64_t>`.

When you do that and use `at()` instead of `[]`, then you get a better view of how your program breaks.  See [the Live Example using std::vector here](http://ideone.com/EBKTG6).

---

As to the "odd number", you are getting a numeric overflow here:

```
int64_t value = pow(tuple, power);
```

If `tuple` is 3, and `power` is `41`, then the value overflows the `int64_t` type.

Maybe you need to use an [arbitrary precision library](https://gmplib.org/) (one that preferably has overloaded the requisite mathematical operators) or write your own, instead of using the "regular" C++ types.  Then you won't or shouldn't overflow.

Comment: Good eye, I updated this and I still get the same odd negative number!

Comment: Take the `std::vector` example.  Change your code to fix the error I pointed out and see if there are other issues with an `out_of_range` exception being thrown.  If after the changes are made, you still get an `out_of_range` exception, then you need to fix the code so that you don't get that error.  Once it doesn't get that error *then* worry about the odd negative number (if it still occurs).

Comment: @August  See my edited answer.  Your code produces a numeric overflow when `pow` is used, starting with `tuple` being 3.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to look into this.. I realized that I probably didn't ask the correct question as I'm pretty far outside of my comfort zone and really do appreciate it.

Comment: @August The code would more or less work correctly in another language that supports big integer types (like the Java's BigInteger class).  I think that Python also has built-in arbitrary precision integers.  Unfortunately, C++ doesn't have this type natively, and thus requires usage of an additional library (or again, you coming up with your own class) to handle this.